# how can i control wifi enabled light bulbs with blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I got one idea that I make one project that how to operate Bulbs using blackberry smartphones
I want to know some manuals and guidance.

Please provide me any useful links.

If it is not possible then please avoid this question.

Please guide me how to Control wifi enabled light bulbs with blackberry phones.

Answer (score 0):

The lights will likely have a URL for controlling the state (on/off). Then your app can call the URL using a web-form. Start by finding the IP address of your light on your WiFi network. Then use the web interface to discover the URL to do the switching. Make a prototype web form on your PC and test that the switch works. Then write a phone app to replicate the form... or find one that someone else has made ;)

Comment: thank you very much for your guidance is there any guides available for for this?

Comment: none that I know of. You could start by looking up the manual on the manufacturer website